# Deleting row from database using html hyperlink servlet

Tags: java, database, servlets

i was wondering how can i refer to method when clicking on hyperlink.

Heres the list of customers and theres a delete option :

```
for(Customers customer : customers)
    {
        out.println(

    "<tbody><tr> "
    + "<td>"+ customer.getFirst_name()+" "+"</td>"
    + "<td>"+ customer.getSurname()+" "+"</td>"
    + "<td>"+ customer.getCode()+" " +"</td></br>"
    + " "+"<td><a href='/Search'>Delete</a></td></tr>" // <--Delete
     );

    }
```

So after clicked on this hyperlink i need to get parameters which have to be sent to my deleteCustomer method which looks like this : \

```
  public void deleteCustomer(Customers c)
 {
    try{
        pst = getConnection().prepareStatement("delete from customer where "
    +" first_name = ?and surname = ? and code = ?");

        pst.setString(1,c.getFirst_name());
        pst.setString(2,c.getSurname());
        pst.setString(3,c.getCode());
        pst.executeUpdate();        

    }catch(Exception e)
    {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {

        closeResources();
    }
```

How can i get these parameters from the correct row and send these parameters to deleteCustomer method so it can deal with deleting the selected row.

Comment: You want to delete row based id(PK) or anything else, Like showing above

Comment: well it can be based on id, or firstname, or surname or even code. But yes a row. Theres a list of customers printed out and each customer has a delete option and i dont know how can i refer the link for the customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
<td><a href="ServletName?id='value'">Delete</a></td>
```

Pass what values you want by href showing like above. In servlet you will get the Id value by using **request.getParameter(id), So based on id you can delete the code now.

Comment: Thanks you! im feeling dumb that i couldnt figure it out on my own :D